# Check if two objects are Equal in Array List

Tags: java, class, arraylist, constructor

I have a main class that creates an arraylist of type Element:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
String input = "";
String id = ""; //combination of letters and numbers
String name = "";

ArrayList<Element> element = new ArrayList<> ();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));

while(!(input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))) {
    System.out.println("Please enter 'e' to enter an element, or 'quit' to quit");
    input = in.readLine();

if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("e")) {

    System.out.println("Please enter a name for the element");
    name = in.readLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter an id for the element");
    id = in.readLine(); 

    element.add(new Element(name,id));
    //only add if id and name don't exist already
}

}

}
```

Then I have a element clas:

```
public class Element {

private String name;
private String id;

public Element(String name, String id) {

this.name = name;
this.id = id;

}


}
```

I want to check before adding an element to a list (it's id and name), to check if another element already in the list already has those exact values (id and name). I know I can use the toString method to do this, but I'm not sure how I can override it to pass on an id and name, before adding the elements to the list. Is their a way to do this? Ideally I'd only want to add an element, if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below overridden `equals` method will work.

```
public class Element {
    private String name;
    private String id;

    public Element(String name, String id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof Element){
            Element element = (Element) obj;
            if(element != null && this.name.equals(element.name) && this.id.equals(element.id)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
  }
```

And then try doing check before adding to your list, as below:

```
        ArrayList<Element> element = new ArrayList<Element> ();
        Element element1 = new Element("a", "1");
        Element element2 = new Element("b", "2");
        Element element3 = new Element("b", "2");
        element.add(element1);
        element.add(element2);
        if(element.contains(element3)){
            System.out.println("Yes");
        } else{
            System.out.println("No");
        }
```

---

**Time for some concept:**

Below is the `contains` implementation from Java:

Part which should concern you is this - `o.equals(elementData[i]`. Internally `equals` method of the object will be used to do equals check, if you have not overridden the `equals` method then the memory location of 2 objects will be compared, and since it would be different `ArrayList.contains` will return `false`, so by overriding the `equals` method we are establishing a logical condition on when to treat 2 `Element` object as same.

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return indexOf(o) >= 0;
}

  public int indexOf(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (elementData[i]==null)
                return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Your equals method does not follow the contract of equals method. It throws NPE for null parameter: For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false

Comment: Just one question, how would I call the equals method in the main class? Something like this: element.equals(element)?

Comment: If you don't needed duplication in your collection, you should use `Set` instead of `List`.

Comment: @A.Panzer I didn't get you, clearly, if you mean `if(element.contains(null)){` will throw NPE then it will not because of this `if (o == null) {` condition in `indexOf` and there is a NULL in the list then `contains` will return true.

Comment: Any chance you can explain how to call the equals method, with what parameter to have within it?

Comment: @hagrawal Take a look at Javadoc of Object.equals method. There are rules for equals() method. This is no matter whether your code pass null or not. Element class might be reused. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Comment: You compare objects like `element3.equals(null)`, `element3.equals(element1)`

Comment: @A.Panzer Which property of `equals` is bothering you? Does my edit addresses your concern?

Comment: @hagrawal Now it looks good. I've mentioned the clause in the first comment. Btw this is one of the most popular interview questions and Java certification.

Comment: Hey I just noticed with your comment, it's not using my while loop. Problem is I have to use it, the values in the constructor can't be predefined, they  have to be user entered.  So when your adding element1 and element2 to the list, I can't do that because I'm not predefining what the user will enter, the values are entered once the user enteres them, any ideas?

Comment: Replace your `element.add(new Element(name,id));` with `Element ele = new Element(name,id);
  if(!element.contains(ele)){
   element.add(ele);`
  }

Comment: Okay thanks, and before that I would call the equals method, with the arguement ele?

Comment: Ahh okay, I just learned that "contains method you will see that it uses the equals() method to evaluate if two objects are the same." Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `Set`. It is a data structure that does exactly what you want it to - it can't contain duplicates. In order for the set to work, you should have a correct implementation of the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of your class.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use anything other than an arraylist.

Comment: You should still override the `equals()` method and rely on the `contains` method of the `ArrayList`... But it will be grossly inefficient

Comment: @DanailAlexiev Please specify which implementation of `Set` you are recommending. Why `contains` will be inefficient?

Comment: @hagrawal The `Set` implementation depend on what you needed. You can use a simple `HashCode` or if you what keep the order you can use `LinkedHashSet.`

Answer (score 0):

Override `equals` method of `Element` class. Use `contains` method of `List` to check whether  element is already in the list.